# Server not delivering response

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm new to node.js and was wondering why this was not working as planned. I used,

```
res.end("Hello world")
```

in the past to display "Hello World" on the page.

Now, using the following code, it seems as though it is listening at the same address, but I navigate there and it doesn't go to the page! It's like [express](https://expressjs.com/) isn't delivering the response. I'm very confused.

### web.js

```
const http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    //res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

### index.html (same directory)

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>
        This is title
    </title>
</header>

<body>
    Hello world
</body>

</html>
```

### Console Output

```
Atom Runner: web.js

Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Nope! sorry Ill include the output

Comment: And in your browser's debugger?

Comment: Try res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));

Comment: More like, response.sendFile...

Comment: Unfortunately no luck @RamsingNadeem

Ill take a look in browser debugger. The page doesnt load, it just times out trying to load (the loading webpage circle just keeps on going)

Comment: I don't think you're using your express application.  You attach routes to it, but you don't tell it to listen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't actually using express.  You are attaching routes to it, but you are creating a separate server object and having **that** listen.  You should have something more like this:

```
const http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile('index.html');
});

// Have the actual express app listen, not server
app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Express' intention is to wrap the boiler plate that is involved with creating a server in node.js.  Take a look at Express [Hello world example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).  That example doesn't even `require` the `http` module:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into it further. Seems I was confused about what the express module actually does